# iphone loss of network connection when submitting form

Tags: php, iphone, forms

i have an upload form for details and attachments.

it works fine on desktop however when I try this on my iphone4 and 5 i hit upload and it just says safari cannot open the page because the network connection was lost...

my form saves documents to a folder, and uploads to MySQL database

any ideas?

**Upload_portal.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>upload Portal</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">




    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <img src="img/logo.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div><!-- END ROW -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 topBar">
            <h1>
              Premium Choice Upload portal
            </h1>
            <p>
              Welcome to the Premium Choice upload portal where you can securely send us all your documents. You can also request a copy of your documents
            </p>
        </div>
      </div><!-- END ROW -->
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" style="font-size:1.2em;"><!-- THIS IS THE 1st section -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 sectionHeader">
              <h2> Section 1: Personal Details </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 colClear">
              Select your type of policy:<strong style="color:red; font-size:1.2em;">*</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 colClear">
              <select class="select" name="pol_type"> 
                <option selected="selected" value="Private Car">Private Car</option>
                <option value="Commercial Vehicle">Commercial Vehicle</option>
                <option value="Motorcycle">Motorcycle</option>   
              </select> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding:0;">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 colClear">
                Customer reference <strong style="color:red; font-size:1.2em;">*</strong><br/>
                <input id="reference" type="text" name="reference" value="<?php echo $_GET['ref']; ?>"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 colClear">
                    Email Address <strong style="color:red; font-size:1.2em;">*</strong><br/>
                  <input id="email" type="text" name="email"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
                                if(!empty($_SESSION['errors'][1])){
                                    $output =  "<div class='col-xs-12' style='color:red;'>";


                                    $output .= $_SESSION['errors'][1];


                                    $output .= "</div>";
                                    echo $output;
                                }
            ?>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 colClear">
              First Name <strong style="color:red; font-size:1.2em;">*</strong><br/>
              <input id="firstName" type="text" name="first_name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 colClear">
              last Name <strong style="color:red; font-size:1.2em;">*</strong><br/>
              <input id="lastName" type="text" style="float:right;" name="last_name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 colClear" style="padding:0;">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                Vehicle registration <strong style="color:red; font-size:1.2em;">*</strong><br/>
                <input id="reg" type="text" name="registration"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                Contact Number <strong style="color:red; font-size:1.2em;">*</strong><br/>
                <input id="number" type="text" style="float:right;" name="number"/>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6"><!-- THIS IS THE 2nd section -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 sectionHeader">
              <h2> Section 2: Send us your documents online</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" style="font-size:0.9em;">
              <p class="colClear">Attach your scanned documents as JPG,PDF,DOC,TIF,PNG,GIF (Maximum 20MB)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-offset-2 uploadSection">
              <div class="col-xs-12 colClear">
                <input class="colClear" type="file" size="40" name="pictures[]" />

              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 colClear">
                <input class="colClear" type="file" size="40" name="pictures[]" />

              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 colClear">
                <input class="colClear" type="file" size="40" name="pictures[]" />

              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 colClear">
                <input class="colClear" type="file" size="40" name="pictures[]" />

              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 colClear">
                <input class="colClear" type="file" size="40" name="pictures[]" />

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div><!-- END OF ROW -->
        <div class="colClear"></div>
        <div class="colClear"></div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="col-lg-12 sectionHeader colClear">
              <h2> Section 3: Request a copy of your documents</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" style="font-size:1em;">
              <p>Do you have any other queries or copy document requests?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <textarea name="comments">

              </textarea><br/><br/>
              <p class="text-center" style="font-size:0.75em;">We are unable to send any documents via email. If you have requested such items, these will follow via first</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="col-lg-12 sectionHeader colClear">
              <h2 class="text-center"> Submit your request </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 colClear">
              <input type="submit" class="button colClear" value="" />   
                <p style="font-size:0.75em;">
                    <strong>Please Note</strong><br>
                    Our office hours are 9am-8pm Mon-Fri & 9am-3pm Sat which means any requests submitted outside of these hours will be dealt with the next working day.<br/><br/>
                    Photographs taken with a low resolution camera are not acceptable and we may also ask you to send us the original proof in the post. 

                </p>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Upload.php (form proccess file):**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['errors'] = array();
require_once("includes/db_connection.php");
require_once("includes/functions.php");
require_once("Mail.php");
require_once("Mail/mime.php");

    $errors = array();

    //Variables from $_POST
        $ref = mysql_prep($_POST['reference']);
        $type = mysql_prep($_POST['pol_type']);
        $first_name = mysql_prep($_POST['first_name']);
        $last_name = mysql_prep($_POST['last_name']);
        $reg = mysql_prep($_POST['registration']);
        $number = mysql_prep($_POST['number']);
        $email = mysql_prep($_POST['email']);    
        $comments = mysql_prep($_POST['comments']);
        $date = date("d/m/Y");
        $full_name = $first_name . " " . $last_name;
    //Validations:
        //1) There needs to be at least one upload
        $total_files = count(array_filter($_FILES['pictures']['name']));
        if($total_files < 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['errors'][0] = "No files have been uploaded!";
        }
        //2) Reference needs to be certain length
        if(strlen($ref) !== 8)
        {
            $_SESSION['errors'][1] = "client reference must be a number, and must be 8 digits long";
        }
        //3) All Fields need to be filled
        if($type == "" || $first_name == "" || $last_name == "" || $reg == "" || $number == "" || $email == "")
        {
            $_SESSION['errors'][2] = "All Fields must have a value!";
        }
        //3) Email must be valid
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $_SESSION['errors'][4] = "Email must be valid";
        }   
        //4) Files size limit to 20MB
        $total_size = 0;
        foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["size"] as $size) 
        {
            $total_size = $total_size + $size;  
        }        
            if($total_size > 1e+7)
            {
                $_SESSION['errors'][3] = "File size limit is 20MB, your files are too big!";
            }























// If there are no errors in the validation then continue with script
if(empty($_SESSION['errors']))
{

    //Calls the function to upload the files/details to database, (Requires post variables);
    //insert_upload($ref,$type,$first_name,$last_name,$reg,$number,$email,$comments,$connection);

    $img_count = 0;
    $img_name1 = "";
    $img_name2 = "";
    $img_name3 = "";
    $img_name4 = "";
    $img_name5 = "";
    $newimg_count = 0;
    $newimg_name1 = "";
    $newimg_name2 = "";
    $newimg_name3 = "";
    $newimg_name4 = "";
    $newimg_name5 = "";
            //Foreach files uplaoded place the file name into variable to go into table for later reference.
            foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["name"] as $key => $Name) 
            {
                $img_count++;
                    if($img_count == 1)
                    {
                        $img_name1 = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
                        if($img_name1 !== "")
                        {
                            $newimg_count++;
                            $newimg_name1 = $newimg_count . $img_name1;
                        }else
                        {
                            $newimg_name1 = $img_name1;
                        }   
                        echo $newimg_name1; 
                    }elseif($img_count == 2)
                    {
                        $img_name2 = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
                        if($img_name2 !== "")
                        {
                            $newimg_count++;
                            $newimg_name2 = $newimg_count . $img_name2;
                        }else
                        {
                            $newimg_name2 = $img_name2;
                        }   
                        echo $newimg_name2; 
                    }elseif($img_count == 3)
                    {
                        $img_name3 = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
                        if($img_name3 !== "")
                        {
                            $newimg_count++;
                            $newimg_name3 = $newimg_count . $img_name3;
                        }else
                        {
                            $newimg_name3 = $img_name3;
                        }   
                        echo $newimg_name3; 
                    }elseif($img_count == 4)
                    {
                        $img_name4 = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
                        if($img_name4 !== "")
                        {
                            $newimg_count++;
                            $newimg_name4 = $newimg_count . $img_name4;
                        }else
                        {
                            $newimg_name4 = $img_name4;
                        }
                        echo $newimg_name4; 
                    }else
                    {
                        $img_name5 = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
                        if($img_name5 !== "")
                        {
                            $newimg_count++;
                            $newimg_name5 = $newimg_count . $img_name5;
                        }else
                        {
                            $newimg_name5 = $img_name5;
                        }
                        echo $newimg_name5; 
                    } 
            }   
    $query =  "INSERT INTO ";
    $query .= "customers";  
    $query .= "(`reference`, `policy_type`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `registration`, `number`, `email`, `doc1`, `doc2`, `doc3`,`doc4`,`doc5`,`comments`,`date`) ";
    $query .= "VALUES ('{$ref}', '{$type}', '{$first_name}', '{$last_name}' , '{$reg}' , '{$number}' , '{$email}' , '{$newimg_name1}' , '{$newimg_name2}' , '{$newimg_name3}', '{$newimg_name4}', '{$newimg_name5}','{$comments}','{$date}')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $_SESSION['query'] = $query;



























    $target_dir = "docs/";

    //IF/ELSE the folder is already created...
        if(!file_exists($target_dir . $ref . "/"))
        {//Create folder named 1 inside the customer ref folder.
            mkdir($target_dir . $ref . "/" . "1" . "/", 0775, true);
            $count = 0;
        }else
        {//Create new folder inside customer ref folder 
            //count the amount of folders inside docs/$ref/
            $find_folders = glob($target_dir . $ref . "/" . "*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);
            $count = count($find_folders);
            //create new folder inside $ref/ using count+1 to make the folder increase by 1
                $new_folder = $count +1;
                mkdir($target_dir . $ref . "/" . $new_folder . "/", 0775, true);        
        }
                //IF count exists then the $target_file changes to the new folder...
                    if($count > 0)
                        {
                            $target_file = $target_dir . $ref . "/" . $new_folder . "/";  
                        }else
                        {//else use first directory
                            $target_file = $target_dir . $ref . "/" . "1" . "/";
                        }
    //Loop through files and place them into $target_file...
        $namecount = 0;
        foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["name"] as $key => $Name) 
        {

                $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
                $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
                if($name !== ""){
                    $namecount++;
                    $newname = $namecount . $name;
                }else{
                    $newname = $name;
                }
                echo $newname . "</br>";
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_file . "$newname");

        }





$from = " Upload portal <upload-portal@premiumchoiceinsurance.co.uk>";
$to = "Matthew <matthew.smart@premiumchoice.co.uk>";
$subject = "Document Upload, Policy: 123456789";
$host = "ssl://secure.emailsrvr.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "upload-portal@premiumchoiceinsurance.co.uk";
$password = "C4r1n5ur4nc3";
$crlf = "\n";
$web_root = "http://test.premiumchoiceinsurance.co.uk.php54-3.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/";
$link1 = "<a href='" . $web_root . $target_file . $newimg_name1 . "'>{$img_name1}</a>";
$link2 = "<a href='" . $web_root . $target_file . $newimg_name2 . "'>{$img_name2}</a>";
$link3 = "<a href='" . $web_root . $target_file . $newimg_name3 . "'>{$img_name3}</a>";
$link4 = "<a href='" . $web_root . $target_file . $newimg_name4 . "'>{$img_name4}</a>";
$link5 = "<a href='" . $web_root . $target_file . $newimg_name5 . "'>{$img_name5}</a>";


$html = "
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div style='width:100%;height:500px;'>
    <p>This email was made from the Document Upload Portal</p>

    <table style='width:400px;'>
        <tr style='background-color:#FFFFCC; height:50px;'>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                Customer reference: 
            </td>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                {$ref}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style='background-color:#CCCCB2; height:50px;'>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                Policy Type: 
            </td>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                {$type}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style='background-color:#FFFFCC; height:50px;'>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                Vehicle Registration 
            </td>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                {$reg}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style='background-color:#CCCCB2; height:50px;'>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                name: 
            </td>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                {$full_name}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style='background-color:#FFFFCC; height:50px;'>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                telephone:
            </td>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                {$number}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style='background-color:#CCCCB2; height:50px;'>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                Email:
            </td>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                {$email}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style='background-color:#FFFFCC; height:50px;'>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                Attached Files:
            </td>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                {$link1}<br/>
                {$link2}<br/>
                {$link3}<br/>
                {$link4}<br/>
                {$link5}<br/>

            </td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
    <table style='width:400px;'>
        <tr style='background-color:#CCCCB2; height:50px;'>
            <td style='text-align:center;'>
                Comments:<br/><br/>
                {$comments}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
";
$headers = array (
              'From' => $from,
              'To' => $to,
              'Subject' => $subject
          );

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'MIME-Version' => 1,
    'Content-type' => 'text/html;charset=iso-8859-1'
    ));


        $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

        // Setting the body of the email

        $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

        $body = $mime->get();
        $headers = $mime->headers($headers);


$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);




        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "http://test.premiumchoiceinsurance.co.uk.php54-3.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/thanks.php"
      </script>';

}else//if there are errors in validation then redirect to index and show them
{
    redirect_to('upload_portal.php?ref=' . $ref);
}//END OF empty session




?>
```

Comment: I have a lot of code though, i can add it all on if you want? i just though id ask incase there was a known issue

Comment: we're not going to read through a wall of code. reduce what you've got to the smallest sample that causes the same problem. e.g. if you've got 500 form fields, but the same form with only one field triggers the same probelm, then we don't need the other 499 (useless) bits of html.

Comment: i have updated notes

Answer (score 0):

When posting image from iphone to a server behind nginx (ie aws beanstalk), I got I got a “Safari cannot load the page because the network connection was lost” and chrome "unable to connect to the internet".  Turns out the image was greater than 1M nginx default for client_max_body_size.  (Seems to work from desktop which is strange.)  The solution for me was to increase that parameter value to something more appropriate.

On beanstalk, the solution is to create a folder at root of distribution file called .ebextensions and put file named nginx.config (only matters it ends with .config) with following code:

`files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 50M;`